# .htaccess or cPanel redirects. Redirect pagename in folder to subdomain/pagename (all folder contents)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cpanel

I am trying to get a redirect set up for my site. I have three **subdomains** which I use

1) (www.)mysite.com

2) sub.mysite.com

3) anothersub.mysite.com

I initially didn't use subdomains and had all my pages in a `www.mysite.com/*.php` format.

I am trying to add a redirect to make all the pages under the `/myfolder/` folder redirect to `sub.mysite.Com/` (NB sub is the same name on my site as the myfolder folder)

I have tried setting up a redirect through cPanel but all the combinations have resulted in 404 errors when I try them. I have also tried various things in `.htaccess` which resulted in many 404 errors.

I added a simple redirect in cPanel and get the following

e.g.

```
www.mysite.com/myfolder/myfolder_mypagename.php
```

should redirect to

```
sub.mysite.Com/myfolder_mypagename.php
```

but instead it redirects to

`sub.mysite.com/_mypagename.php` (missing out the "myfolder" part of the pagename)

Can you assist me in this please? It's driving me bonkers and my hosting company said it wasn't possible (which I find hard to believe!)

Comment: normaly, when you add a subdomain through cpanel, you can point it to a directory. So basicaly, you just need to point it to the directory you want

Comment: If I add it through cpanel it results in the example I listed above where the myfolder part of the filename is stripped out. I don't think it likes the fact that the subdomain name is also contained within the pagename.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming your are facing the issue that, when creating a subdomain through cpanel and pointing it to the desired directory, some part of the urls get striped.

Create you subdomain through cpanel, and make it point to the root directory (just like www.mysite.com), then use this in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^myfolder/(.*)$ http://sub.mysite.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm getting 500 server errors with the above edited to match my site now!

Comment: Check if mod_rewrite is enabled on your server

Comment: I'm 99% sure it is. Unfortunately I've got to head off for the weekend now but I'll check back when I can to see if there are any other suggestions. Many thanks so far.